# if statement and for loop to append new data to original data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops, nested-if

I have some model outputs that I want to integrate back into the original data file. I was able to do this using nested ifelse(), however I want a way to generalize the process so that I can run it as a batch process across multiple data sets. This is what I originally tried.

The model outputs correspond to time chunks, while each original data point is associated with a discrete time.

I decided to manually run one day at a time (here is an example of one parameter on one day), and with this very large and ugly ifelse was able to correctly aggregate the data.

```
track[,"phase"]= ifelse((phaseTable1$start[1]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[1]), phaseTable1$phase[1],
                  ifelse((phaseTable1$start[2]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[2]), phaseTable1$phase[2],
                         ifelse((phaseTable1$start[3]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[3]), phaseTable1$phase[3],
                                ifelse((phaseTable1$start[4]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[4]), phaseTable1$phase[4],
                                       ifelse((phaseTable1$start[5]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[5]), phaseTable1$phase[5],
                                              ifelse((phaseTable1$start[6]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[6]), phaseTable1$phase[6],
                                                     ifelse((phaseTable1$start[7]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[7]), phaseTable1$phase[7],
                                                            ifelse((phaseTable1$start[8]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[8]), phaseTable1$phase[8],
                                                                   ifelse((phaseTable1$start[9]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[9]), phaseTable1$phase[9],
                                                                          ifelse((phaseTable1$start[10]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[10]), phaseTable1$phase[10],
                                                                                 ifelse((phaseTable1$start[11]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[11]), phaseTable1$phase[11],
                                                                                        ifelse((phaseTable1$start[12]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[12]), phaseTable1$phase[12],
                                                                                               ifelse((phaseTable1$start[13]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[13]), phaseTable1$phase[13],
                                                                                                      ifelse((phaseTable1$start[14]<=track$Time)& (track$Time<phaseTable1$end[14]), phaseTable1$phase[14],
                                                                                                             ifelse((phaseTable1$start[15]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[15]), phaseTable1$phase[15],
                                                                                                                    ifelse((phaseTable1$start[16]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[16]), phaseTable1$phase[16],
                                                                                                                           ifelse((phaseTable1$start[17]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[17]), phaseTable1$phase[17],
                                                                                                                                  ifelse((phaseTable1$start[18]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[18]), phaseTable1$phase[18],
                                                                                                                                         ifelse((phaseTable1$start[19]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[19]), phaseTable1$phase[19],
                                                                                                                                                ifelse((phaseTable1$start[20]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[20]), phaseTable1$phase[20],
                                                                                                                                                       ifelse((phaseTable1$start[21]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[21]), phaseTable1$phase[21],
                                                                                                                                                              ifelse((phaseTable1$start[22]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[22]), phaseTable1$phase[22],
                                                                                                                                                                     ifelse((phaseTable1$start[23]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[23]), phaseTable1$phase[23],
                                                                                                                                                                            ifelse((phaseTable1$start[24]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[24]), phaseTable1$phase[24], 
                                                                                                                                                                                   ifelse((phaseTable1$start[25]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[25]), phaseTable1$phase[25],
                                                                                                                                                                                          ifelse((phaseTable1$start[26]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[26]), phaseTable1$phase[26], 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 ifelse((phaseTable1$start[27]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[27]), phaseTable1$phase[27],
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ifelse((phaseTable1$start[28]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[28]), phaseTable1$phase[28],
                                                                                                                                                                                                              ifelse((phaseTable1$start[29]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[29]), phaseTable1$phase[29],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ifelse((phaseTable1$start[30]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[30]), phaseTable1$phase[30],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ifelse((phaseTable1$start[31]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[31]), phaseTable1$phase[31], 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ifelse((phaseTable1$start[32]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[32]), phaseTable1$phase[32],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ifelse((phaseTable1$start[33]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[33]), phaseTable1$phase[33],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ifelse((phaseTable1$start[34]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[34]), phaseTable1$phase[34],
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ifelse((phaseTable1$start[35]<=track$Time)& (track$Time< phaseTable1$end[35]), phaseTable1$phase[35],phaseTable1$phase[35]

                                                                                                                                                                                                                      )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

This worked, however it is quite unwieldy and the number of nested conditions varies from day to day within the data.

I tried to rework this into a more practical loop

```
for ( j in 1:nrow(phaseTable1)){
if((phaseTable1$start[j]<=track$Time)&(track$Time< phaseTable1$end[j])){track$tau== phaseTable1$tau[j]}

 }
```

and constantly get this warning which results in no data being aggregated

```
In if ((phaseTable1$start[j] <= track$Time) & (track$Time <  ... the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I tried it again like this

```
    for ( j in 1:nrow(phaseTable1)){
        track$phase<-ifelse(((phaseTable1$star [j]<=track$Time)&(track$Time< phaseTable1$end[j])),  phaseTable1$phase[j],"")))
}
```

And the new columns appear in the data frame but they are empty.

I tried again using a wrapper from the thatssorandom package recommended in a blog post, which also resulted in an error.

```
for ( j in 1:nrow(phaseTable1)){
ie(
  i(((phaseTable1$start[j]<=track$Time)&(track$Time< phaseTable1$end[j])),track$phase<- phaseTable1$phase[j]),
e("na"))

  }
```

Is there an obvious mistake I'm making or is there another solution to achieve what I am trying to do? I admit I'm a relatively amateur r user, and I have explored other ifelse forum questions but haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a working loop that allows me to run my models day by day within the dataframe. If I am able to get this next loop to run then I will be able to nest it into the first loop, and will be able to aggregate the data in batches. Any insight as to what the solution might be will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Without a data set to work with, this can be accomplished with `findInterval`

```
df1 <- data.frame(start = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-08-07 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 24))
df1$end <-   df1$start + 3600
df1$phase <- letters[seq_len(nrow(df1))]

v <- findInterval(c(as.POSIXct("2017-08-07 02:38:24"), as.POSIXct("2017-08-07 21:59:59")), df1$start)
df1$phase[v]
[1] "c" "v"
```

Unless there is a gap between the intervals, the end time is not needed

---

For the first error, take a look at `?&`

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

Second error: typo as `phaseTable1$star [j]` should be `phaseTable1$start[j]`

Third error: typo as `i` should be `if`

Comment: This is great, thanks! I didn't know about findInterval(). The distinction between the long and short form & was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to be working. Had to rethink how I set up the loops.

```
for ( j in 1:nrow(phaseTable1)){
for ( k in 1:nrow(track)){
if((phaseTable1$start[j]<=track$Time[k])&(track$Time[k]< phaseTable1$end[j])){track$model[k]= phaseTable1$model[j]}

if((phaseTable1$start[j]<=track$Time[k])&(track$Time[k]< phaseTable1$end[j])){track$phase[k]= phaseTable1$phase[j]}

if((phaseTable1$start[j]<=track$Time[k])&(track$Time[k]< phaseTable1$end[j])){track$tau[k]= phaseTable1$tau[j]}

if((phaseTable1$start[j]<=track$Time[k])&(track$Time[k]< phaseTable1$end[j])){track$eta[k]= phaseTable1$eta[j]}

}

}
```

Comment: nested `for` loops should not be required for this.  if you post some sample data with desired output there is likely a better way to do this.